# Bitcoin and Encryption

Tags: encryption, bitcoin

I'm doing a school project on the security of bitcoin, and I was just wondering if anyone could explain, possibly with credible sources how bitcoin wallets use the passphrase as encryption, what is meant by EVP ("The passphrase is converted to a key/iv using EVP") and just any information that people have about the encryption of bitcoin wallet would be much appreciated.

Thanks <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear, wallet encryption has nothing to do with the bitcoin protocol. If you were to create a new client, you can encrypt your private key(s) however you want.

According to [this wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_encryption) the original bitcoin client hashes the passphrase with SHA-512 and then uses a key derivation algorithm described [in the official documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html). The actual encryption is AES-256.

EVP ("Envelope") is just a tool of openssl that encapsulates crypo implemenations so that you can change the underlying algorithm without changing too much code.